# Why can't I read Dropdown values by Formik in React?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui, formik, yup

I am using Formik and Yup for a form control in react application. I use also Semantic UI. In the application, when I click the submit button, whereas I can read the values from FormField elements and see them on Console, I can not get the values from Dropdown elements and they appear blank on Console. How can I solve this out?

```
 return (
    <div>
      <Card fluid>
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>Create A New Job Ad</Card.Header>
          <Divider inverted />
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={jobAdCreateSchema}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
              console.log(values);
            }}
          >
            <Form className="ui form">
              <label>Job Title</label>
              <FormField>
                <Field name="jobTitle" placeholder="Select a Job Title"></Field>
              </FormField>
              <FormField>
                <label>City</label>
                <Dropdown
                  name="city"
                  placeholder="Select a City"
                  fluid
                  selection
                  options={cityOption}
                />
              </FormField>
              <FormField>
                <Button color="green" type="submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </FormField>
            </Form>
          </Formik>
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: can you provide a code sandbox ? .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the way the `Dropdown` component is rendered currently. You need to make use of the `setFieldValue` provided by Formik to manually update the Formik state.

```
 <Formik
    initialValues={{
      city: ""
    }}
    onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
  >
    {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2)}</pre>

        <Dropdown
          selection
          placeholder="Select a City"
          options={[
            { value: "NY", text: "New York" },
            { value: "LA", text: "Los Angeles" },
            { value: "SF", text: "San Fransico" }
          ]}
          value={values.city}
          onChange={(value) => setFieldValue("city", value)}
        />
      </div>
    )}
  </Formik>
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-fzlwd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your answer really helped a lot. I solved the problem with your solution. Thank you very much!

Now I have problem with TextArea and Date items. Do you have any idea for this as well? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69184345/why-cant-i-get-values-of-date-and-text-area-in-formik

Comment: Can you explain what is `pet1` in `{values.pet1}` ?