# Why can't I get values of Date and Text Area in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, formik, yup

I am using Formik and Yup for a form control in React application. I use also Semantic UI. In the application, when I click the submit button, whereas I can read the values from FormField elements and see them on Console, I can not get the value of Date and Text Area elements and they appear blank on Console. How can I solve this out?

Here I define the intial values.

```
const initialValues = {
jobTitle: { id: "" },
deadline: "",
description: "",
```

};

Then here I try to get the values from form element

```
return (
<div>
  <Card fluid>
    <Card.Content>
      <Card.Header>Create A New Job Ad</Card.Header>
      <Divider inverted />
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={jobAdCreateSchema}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          handleSubmit(values);
        }}
      >
        {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
          <div>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2)}</pre>

            <Form className="ui form">
              <FormField>
                <label>Job Title</label>
                <Dropdown
                  selection
                  placeholder="Select a Job Title"
                  name="jobTitle"
                  fluid
                  options={jobTitleOption}
                  value={values.jobTitle.id}
                  onChange={(_, { value }) =>
                    setFieldValue("jobTitle.id", value)
                  }
                />
              </FormField>
              <FormField>
                <label>Application Deadline</label>
                <input
                  name="deadline"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  type="date"
                  placeholder="Application Deadline"
                  value={values.deadline}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                />
              </FormField>
              <FormField>
                <label>Job Description</label>
                <TextArea
                  name="description"
                  placeholder="Job Description"
                  style={{ minHeight: 100 }}
                  value={values.description}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                />
              </FormField>
              <FormField>
                <Button color="green" type="submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </FormField>
            </Form>
          </div>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Card.Content>
  </Card>
</div>
```

);

Answer (score 1):

`formik` isn't defined, so your assigning an onChange function that doesn't exist.

Destructure `handleChange` from the argument, then assign it to the inputs like so:

```
{({ values, setFieldValue, handleChange }) => (
  //...

  <input
    name="deadline"
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
    type="date"
    placeholder="Application Deadline"
    value={values.deadline}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
)}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-semantic-kd0uy?file=/index.js)